# How does Temperature of a system change if doing work on the environment? Can the temperature of the system increase?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, work

I am just a bit confused about how to relate Temperature and work. If my system is doing work on the environment, could the temperature increase? I know that you can lower energy while raising entropy but I just don't understand the relation between the work and temperature. I'm assuming no since if work is done, usually heat would be converted to work so their would only be a temperature loss.

Comment: temperature is proportional to the internal energy of the system , obviously when you do work you are losing internal energy hence your temperature is reduced. It is simple to think of temperature as average Kinetic energy of the substance , so that kinetic energy reduces when internally energy is low hence the answer is no

Comment: If you add enough heat, you can raise the temperature even if the system does work.

Answer (score 9):

I will assume that the system you are talking about is adiabatic because if it isn't we can cool or heat it to change its temperature in any desired way independently of whether the system does or receives work. Also no reactions, to keep things simple.

For any process in a closed adiabatic ($Q=0$) system we have
$$\Delta U = W$$

- **Expansion against external pressure** The system does work, i.e., the work is *negative*, therefore $U$ *decreases*, therefore $T$ *drops*
- **Compression by external pressure** The system receives work, i.e., the work is *positive*, therefore $U$ *increases*, therefore $T$ *goes up*

The only way that the system does work *and* its temperature goes up is if we add heat during the expansion.

Comment: Do an experiment. Hook a battery up to a heavy load. Of course, that's a different *kind* of system than the one you're analyzing, but the OP isn't so restricted.

Comment: Ok–closed system, adiabatic and no reaction. Since the OP did not specify, I am free to make assumptions.

Comment: It would be useful to state all the assumptions in the answer, as their violation can break the standard analysis.
I.e. being adiabatic, no reactions, no external field, no initial low-entropy state, etc.

Comment: @M.S. I edited my answer to include no reaction. However listing all possible exceptions (nuclear reactions? black holes? quantum effects? ...) is not pedagogical. Clearly the OP has a simple question about introductory thermodynamics.

Comment: @Themis As pedagogy, abstract mathematical answers employing unstated and unlikely constraints are far poorer than concrete physical answers that can easily be verified by experiment. Physics is not mathematics.

Comment: @JohnDoty No one prevents anyone from writing answers according to their personal philosophies.

Comment: @Themis And I did. But you defended your unphysical answer as "pedagogical".

Comment: @JohnDoty You have the right to call it "unphysical". You also have the right to mock my pedagogy.

Comment: @Themis You are invited to perform a practical experiment that demonstrates your assertion. It is, of course, not impossible, but it's tricky. Reality is messier than symbols on a whiteboard.

Comment: @Themis And you, unfortunately, have the right to the sort of pedagogy that turns out students as clueless as these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIhk9eKOLzQ

Comment: @JohnDoty I am a university professor who teaches thermodynamics , you're welcome to take my course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144698/discussion-between-john-doty-and-themis).

Comment: Let's see, I show you a video by a physics professor at one of the best universities in the world. It demonstrates how badly professors at the best universities are teaching physics, and you respond that you're a university professor.

Comment: Please, let's not make it personal. This is not Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

No constraints on the nature of the system were stated in the question, and without such constraints the answer is that the system might get hotter or colder.

For hotter, the obvious case is a battery. Batteries get hot when doing work at a high rate. This is an easy experiment.

Themis's answer covers the sort of system that will get colder.

Comment: Some answers (on other questions) are formed as "the previous answer is quite good, I'll add some notices to it."
If your answer would be formed that way, with stating all the implicit assumptions in the previous answer, it would serve it well.
But yeah, it's your answer, I can only suggest.

Comment: @M.S. There is no previous answer, my simple answer came first.

Comment: Sorry, then I mean the other answer. I just meant that your answer suggests caveats, and that it could be made more complete on that. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

> If my system is doing work on the environment, could the temperature
> increase?

It depends on the path between the initial and final equilibrium states and the type of system. One example where it can is where the system is an ideal gas where internal energy depends only on temperature.

For any system, the first law for a closed (no mass transfer) system is

$$\Delta U=Q-W\tag{1}$$

Where $Q$ is positive if heat is added to the system and $W$ is positive if work is done by the system on the environment.

For an ideal gas, any process

$$\Delta U =nC_{v}\Delta T\tag{2}$$

Substituting eq (2) into eq (1)

$$nC_{v}\Delta T=Q-W\tag{3}$$

So if the path from the initial equilibrium state to the final equilibrium state involves more heat added to the system than work done by the system, eq (3) tells us the temperature will increase in the case of an ideal gas.

An example of such a possible path is an isobaric expansion where work is done and heat is added, followed by an isochoric (constant volume) heat addition that increases the pressure where heat is added with no work done.

Hope this helps.